# Create Object from Subclass-Object

Tags: ruby, oop

say I've got 2 Classes:

```
Class Foo
    attr_accessor :bar
end

Class Baz < Foo
end
```

I'm creating an Instance of `Foo` and then want to have an Instance of `Baz` with the Data of the Foo Instance in it:

```
f = Foo.new(:bar => "Hi World")

# Doesnt work?
b = Baz.new(f)
```

How to do it?

Comment: Why don't you create instance of `Baz` directly instead?

Comment: Since a `Baz` *is a* `Foo`, I don't see why you would need a reference to both types.

Comment: disregarding my example code, is it generally possible to create objects from subclass-object or do I have to write a class method like `Baz.create_from_foo(foo)` ?

Comment: What does it even *mean* to "create an object from a subclass object"??? A subclass object already *is* an instance of the superclass, and creating a superclass "from" a subclass is bass-ackwards.

Comment: I think the OP is getting _inheritance_ confused with _composition_

Answer (score 2):

> an instance of `Baz` with the data of the `Foo` instance in it

Since your constructor already accepts attributes as a hash, you could create a method to return `Foo`'s attributes as a hash:

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :bar

  def initialize(attributes={})
    @bar = attributes[:bar]
  end

  def attributes
    {:bar => bar}
  end
end

class Baz < Foo
end
```

Now you can create a `Baz` instance from these attributes:

```
f = Foo.new(:bar => "Hi World")   #=> #<Foo:0x007fd09a8614c0 @bar="Hi World">
f.attributes                      #=> {:bar=>"Hi World"}

b = Baz.new(f.attributes)         #=> #<Baz:0x007fd09a861268 @bar="Hi World">
```

Comment: Good solution. Warning: If you set `Foo.new(:bar => Array.new)` or some other object and then set `Baz.new`, both will refer to the exact same Array. Meaning, adding something to `f.bar` will alter `b.bar`.

Comment: @CharlesCaldwell that's right, `f.bar.upcase!` affects `b.bar`, too (it's the same object). The constructor / setter has to *copy* the object if this is not desired.